# Ruby on Rails: Getting Params from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

On Rails 4, I am having trouble getting the params from a URL in my controller.

I have two models with a has_many and belongs_to association, let's call them Books and Pages. I want to create a new Page record and have it link to the Book model depending on which book the user was visiting when they clicked on the "Create" button (i.e. if a user was on the Jurassic Park book page and clicked "Create," I want to create a new page that is associated with the Jurassic Park book).

Here is the create link from my view:

```
<%= link_to "Create page", new_page_path(:book => @book.id), :id => "submit-button" %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def new
  @page = Page.new
end

def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book])
  @page = Product.new(page_params)
  @page.book_id = @book.id
  if @page.save
    flash[:success] = "Page Submitted!"
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

> "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#create - Couldn't
>   find Book without an ID"

Am I doing this completely wrong? I know Rails 4 changed the way params work which is the same syntax as getting the URL parameters, so perhaps that is what is causing this issue.

Edit: I also tried getting the params from 'new' as a variable and then using that as the id, but I get the same error message.

Comment: Hi. In Rails4 strong_parameters is default. So you should give permit every parameter what you get from a url or form. In your case, you should have a `book_params` and this book_params could use with find.

Comment: `@book = Book.find(book_params)`

under `private` in your controller

`def book_params
  params[:book].permit(:id, :name)
end`

Answer (score 0):

new_page_path will call the 'new' action here which is GET. It will not call the 'create' action as you expect. Ideally you want to call 'create' action. Try this:

```
button_to 'Create Page', pages_path(:book => @book.id), :method => :post
```

link_to generally should point to GET actions only. It is preferred to user button_to for such things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for (note :id instead of :book):

```
<%= link_to "Create page", new_page_path(:id => @book.id), :id => "submit-button" %>
```

Then update your create method to:

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```